# Boost Apache2 up to 4 cores usage, running PHP

Tags: php, apache2, multiprocessing, command-line-interface

---

READ FURTHER BELOW at CLI, FOR THE CLI QUESTION, WHICH JUST ADDED TO THE CONVERSATION! THX!

---

I have written a script which processes an xml file of around 160'000 entries with 48.1MB and a text file of 150'000 entries with 31.1MB, including some directory searches for external files, heavy interlinking and recursive checks and the result formatted and all saved into html files.

Surely, I did review the program couple times and ended up with the most efficient code I could think of. This is a local program and the generator doesn't need to run regularly. One could argue that I should use an other language than PHP, but PHP with simplexml, etc. just works the best for me and for this purpose. Also a set_time_limit('70000') doesn't bother me.

Although, here my question, is it possible to make the apache2 on my linux system, use my 4 CPU cores running my PHP script? 
Even if I split the process and make several request's simultaneously, the CPU usage can't go above 1 CPU at a time.

I googled this topic but couldn't find a solution, so I may have to just run it over night, even though, I would appreciate some help to boost that thing!!!

ADDED INFO - And here a picture of my processes: [image]

CLI:
I need to call my index.php in the linux terminal to execute. But I also wanna send four post variables ($_POST['example']) to the script. On top of that, I am looking for having my echos presented in some output file. Could anyone help quickly with the terminal command and the php command to track those 4 post variables inside:

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
   // ...
}
```

? ...sorry but this is my first php-cli interaction. Thx!

Comment: `set_time_limit(0)` would be better than setting it to some arbitrarily high number.

Comment: It would be a lot clearer for everyone if you would leave your question as a question and post how you solved it as an answer.

Comment: not possible:Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

    Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Author's response

This is not a solution but a nice workaround. I clone my virtual machine with the linux/apache2 install to kick in the same process but different parts of the file/process on different vm's, which lets the host system apply one core for each virtual system, that way I could break down the process time by around the factor 4. Thanks for your posts!

===============

If it's local, and you want to run it every now and then, you should probably just invoke it from a `cron` job.  That way, you can spawn a process for each task you are doing.  If you really do want to use PHP for it, you can even invoke PHP to do it from the cron line.

None the less, it sounds like you're doing an inherently single-threaded process anyway, and if you want it faster, should probably use something that isn't PHP for this.

Comment: Yeah, cron is what I am using to run those things out of my presence. Seems like I don't need an i7-2600 CPU but something with one bad ass fast uni CORE CPU. Thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: Hey, the i7 will turn itself into a single-core if it has nothing better to do at the moment :P.  Anyway, you might be able to multithread it by breaking it up.  For example, it "directory searches for external files" sounds like having `find /wherever/ > /somewhere/listOfFiles.txt`, run ahead of time and then search that index file, or something like that.  It does sound like you're probably more IO-bound than anything else though.  Are you sure you're actually maxing out a proc core on this?

Comment: yes, one CPU core is all the time on 100% usage for this. And the directory search is a minor task. Although, thanks... I thought there is a smart way but it seems obvious with the IO-bound. I also got a workaround for this... read my Answer!

Comment: damn, don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, so here it is:

Comment: This is not a solution but a nice workaround. I clone my virtual machine with the linux/apache2 install to kick in the same process but different parts of the file/process on different vm's, which lets the host system apply one core for each virtual system, that way I could break down the process time by around the factor 4.

Thanks for your posts!

Comment: If you can split it into different parts in different VMs, why can't you split it into different parts on the same VM, just calling it multiple times on each part?

Comment: thats exactly my problem, I have done that and due to some reason my vm still only uses one cpu core for those multiple callings. I have no clue why?

Comment: Ah, I (and I think others) interpreted the question as "I have a slow script, where is the magical multithread button?".  That's thoroughly weird though; how are you calling them?

Comment: I don't call them over cli but Firefox or some other browsers. I tested it from within the apache vm as from outside with multiple requests. Just defining the writing function to start at certain lines. so I call one request to make 0-60000, second 60000-120000 and third 120000-end. it seems like apache puts off the second and third request waiting for first to finish.

Comment: That makes some sense; it's probably something chaining the requests (instead of overloading the server, each client gets one request returned at a time).  Splitting the "server" up means that firefox thinks it is different servers, and the apache process actually is different servers.  I would be academically curious if it did the same thing if you directly invoked the parser from cli.

Comment: Got you guys, I am gonna try cli. haven't used that yet and I need to handle some posting variables to the script, which I usually set in the browser. I mean command line is simple, just posting those commands I need to read some manual. Maybe you got a good resource?

Answer (score 2):

No, a single PHP script will never use multiple threads and thus always run on single core.

Depending on how much the things you do depend on each other you couldn't easily split them on multiple threads anyway.

Comment: Yep, exactly the answer I expected, but was worth asking! Thanks!

Comment: This is not a solution but a nice workaround. I clone my virtual machine with the linux/apache2 install to kick in the same process but different parts of the file/process on different vm's, which lets the host system apply one core for each virtual system, that way I could break down the process time by around the factor 4.

Thanks for your posts!

Comment: I tried that, but still my apache uses only one cpu even there are several requests. maybe I could improve my configuration? I mean my apache uses more than 1 cpu on other requests, but not on this particular php-file/prog...

Comment: Why are you using apache for it anyway?

Comment: what environment shall I run php else? xamp (apache for win) won't improve it ether...

Comment: gonna give it a shot... do you have good resources about the usage of cli? I post some variables from a setting screen and have no clue how to do that after I looked at the cli description on php.net. Maybe I am just too lazzy to read carefully but you know how that is, if I could find a better manual, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Spork! It's a php lib allowing you to fork the php process into multiple ones.

```
<?php

use Spork\Deferred\DeferredFactory;
use Spork\ProcessManager;

$manager = new ProcessManager(new DeferredFactory());
$manager->fork(function() {
    // do something in another process!
})->then(function($output, $status) {
    // do something in the parent process when it's done!
});
```

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/spork

Comment: thank you, next time I am gonna try this, I already split the process so it won't really change anything in my script now

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm impressed or horrified by the existence of this library....  It does seem quite useful in certain situations though.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION, THX TO ThiefMaster and Zebediah49 recommending cli and my friend who supported me with the links: http://ch.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php / http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

and here how I call the php through cli:

```
//whenRunFromCLI
//callCLI
//php index.php './data/xyfullFile1.xml' './data/xxfullFile2.utf' 0 60000
//php index.php './data/xyfullFile1.xml' './data/xxfullFile2.utf' 60000 120000
//php index.php './data/xyfullFile1.xml' './data/xxfullFile2.utf' 120000 all
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli'){
    $_POST['xml'] = $argv[1];
    $_POST['example'] = $argv[2];
    @$_POST['rangeFrom'] = $argv[3];
    @$_POST['rangeTo'] = $argv[4];
}
```

and the Result of calling the php file in three terminals:
[image]

I know, I must give some more RAM to my virtual machine, lucky that I still have 8GB spare ;-)

Cheers and peace!