# PHP script (algorithm) - only loops till a certain iteration after which it stops

Tags: php, for-loop, memory, timeout, large-data

I am running an algorithm in PHP which has a lot of data involved. All the processing happens within a nested for loop. Strangely, the outer for loop stops working after 'X' number of iterations (where 'X' is changing all the time I run the script). It takes anywhere between 5 mins to 30mins for the script to crash depending on 'X'. It does not throw out any errors, and only does an incomplete printout of my var_dump (in the first iteration of the outer loop)

These are the precautions I took:
1. I have set the timeout limit in php.ini to be 3600sec (60mins).
2. I am printing out the memory_get_usage() after every outer for loop iteration and i have verified that it is much lesser compared to the max memory allocated to php.
3. I am unsetting arrays once they are used
4. I reuse variable names to limit memory within the forloop
5. I have minimal calls to my DB

I have been solving this for a long time to no avail. So my question is what can be the cause of this problem/how do I go about debugging it. Thank you so much!
Extra: If i work with a much smaller test data size, everything works fine.

Comment: Could you paste some code please?

Comment: The description is lovely, but without code we're next to useless!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously without code this is just a guess, but are you making sure to use a single connection to your database?  If you are reconnecting every time you may get too many connections which could cause an error like this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with utilisation of your server cores and a similar answer/workaround could be found here: [Boost Apache2 up to 4 cores usage, running PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732783/boost-apache2-up-to-4-cores-usage-running-php)

Try running your datasets in parallel.